# Turning -webkit- or -moz- to -o- and -ms-

Tags: css, webkit, background-image, gradient, linear-gradients

Is there any website witch transforms vendor specific form -webkit- or -moz- to -o- and -ms- ?
This is the code:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0%,0% 70%,from(#6a6a6a),to(#222));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 22px 90deg,#222,#6a6a6a);
```

What should i modify to make this code for opera and internet explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Online tools like those listed are useful in helping learn the different formats for making css gradients:
The first site gives you fully commented css detailing which version of each browser the line targets. You copy and paste the code and then edit it to suit your needs.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

http://gradients.glrzad.com/